# ggplot2: How to make a legend only have 2 variables when it automatically makes 6

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to graph data in ggplot2 for a homework assignment, and while the data is fine, I want the legend for the plot to only have 2 options instead of one for every boxplot. Each of the boxes represents a plot of trees (the x-value) that is either evergreen or deciduous according to the color. However, the fill, which I set to be Forest Type for the legend, made a legend for every single plot when I only wanted two symbols in the legend: the gray45-colred box for the 3 evergreen plots and gray69-colored box for the three deciduous plots. In short, how can I make the plot only have 2 symbols to match the 2 colors?

```
ggplot(data=dbh.full, aes(x=Plot, y=D_2017,fill=Plot))+geom_boxplot()+
 labs(x='Plot ID', y='Tree DBH', fill='Forest Type')+
 scale_fill_manual(values=c('gray45','gray45','gray45','gray69','gray69','gray69'))
```

The professor for this class suggested to use `substr()` on the dataframe plot labels, so I would prefer to have the problem solved that way, but I am open to simple solutions as well. I placed a link below to a picture of the graph because I am not high enough of a level to post images.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a binary variable and use it as the variable for `fill`. There many ways to do it, in the example below I detected the levels of `Plot` that had `E` to make `Evergreen`, otherwise `Deciduous`

```
library(tidyverse)

dbh %>% 
  mutate(forest_type = if_else(str_detect(Plot,"E"),"Evergreen","Deciduous")) %>% 
  ggplot(data=dbh.full, aes(x=Plot, y=D_2017,fill=forest_type))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x='Plot ID', y='Tree DBH', fill='Forest Type')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('gray45','gray69'))
```